# text on the picture percentage html css

Tags: html, css, image, text

I have two images, one floats to the left, another to the right. They have the same height, but different widths. I need to put text on the first image (that floats to the left).

I use a css rule for the text (position:relative; top: -20em;), it works but it leaves the tail where the initial position of the text was, so that if I want to place the second row of pics with text, the rows have a gap.

I don't want to use position:absolute, because there will be the second and the third row with pictures and text.

```
<div class="rightDiv picDiv"><img src="pics/about.jpg" width="100%"/>  </div>
<div class="leftDiv textDiv"> <img src="pics/yellow.jpg" width="100%"/>
<p>some text some text </p>
    </div>

<div class="leftDiv picDiv"><img src="pics/about.jpg" width="100%"/>  </div>
<div class="rightDiv textDiv"> <img src="pics/yellow.jpg" width="100%"/><p>another     text another text</p></div>
```

and  the css:

```
.rightDiv{
float:right;
}

.leftDiv{
float:left;
}

.picDiv{
width:58.5660377%;
height:58.3333333%;
}

.textDiv{
width:38.7924528%;
height:58.3333333%;
}

.textDiv p{
position:relative;
top: -20em;
height:58.3333333%;
padding:0 3% 0 1%;
text-align:right;
font-size: 120%;
}
```

I hope I explained it well enought. Also picture attached:

http://maria.talvi.com/screenshot.jpg

How can I place the text or take away this tail so that next images will be placed below?

Answer (score 1):

What is your concern for using position: absolute in your text divs? I'd do it that way, just remember to put that text div nested into the same div where the image is, and set that container div position to relative.

The reason for the "tail", I think, is that since it's a relative positioned div it takes up an initial space in the document flow, no matter what its top edge might be, which you're altering through the "top" css property. Maybe try `margin-top` instead, that should move the whole div.

Or, you can also use the image as the background-image of the container div and just put the text inside that container. That'd need other adjustments in the css if you're going responsive though.

**EDIT:** Actually I didn't notice that you're setting the top property of the paragraph, not the div. Check here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/woCyl

Now, try changing the `top` to `margin-top` :)

You should position the enclosing div, not the paragraph.

**EDIT 2** for further clarity: what you're doing there is position the paragraph related to its parent div, not the div itself.

Comment: Ah, the tail is the white area where the p would have been.